# Insert data to OLAP CUBE by writeback with using Excel

Tags: sql, excel

I am creating budget. To budget I have created OLAP CUBE. In OLAP CUBE by SSAS I have created WriteTable. First problem is that WriteTable has diffrent column than table in fact tabel. Second problem is when I want to insert some data from app DeskStudio to WriteTable by MDX code the data is scattered through all elements of all the dimesions. I know to do not scattered data for all the dimesions I have to use all dimnesions. I have done that, but it still does not work.The purpose is to get data into my WriteTable not scattered, beacuse from WriteTable data is implemented into my fact table by procedure.

At the beginning of the process I have created WriteTable as below:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHDPx.png)
As a result the WriteTable have been created with the column as below:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo7bF.png)
In my main table I have more column as below:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdwmJ.png)
In the second step I have created MDX code and implement this into my compnay budget's app (DeskStudio).
(https:

The third step was to insert some test data into WriteTable via Excel: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxeLY.png)
As a result in my OLAP Cube everything is right:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMgxr.png)
But in my WriteTable the value 1 is divided on all the attributes of the dimensions (16 511 040 rows):
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOXnH.png)
The sum of all the rows is equal 1:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lJoz.png)

I would like to have corect value in WriteTable, because next step is to insert those data into Fact table and from Fact Table it is insert into other table by procedure.